# How to invoke a function of a js file to a typescript component in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have placed the js file in assets folder and imported it in index.html.

I need to use the functions of js file in angular component

via.js

```
var _via_reg_canvas = document.getElementById('region_canvas');
function _via_init() {
       show_message(VIA_NAME + ' (' + VIA_SHORT_NAME + ') version ' + VIA_VERSION +
        '. Ready !', 2 * VIA_THEME_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_MS);

    if (_via_is_debug_mode) {
        document.getElementById('ui_top_panel').innerHTML += '<span>DEBUG MODE</span>';
    }

    document.getElementById('img_fn_list').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('leftsidebar').style.display = 'table-cell';

    project_init_default_project();

  _via_init_reg_canvas_context();
  _via_init_keyboard_handlers();
  _via_init_mouse_handlers();
  image_grid_init();

  show_single_image_view();
  init_leftsidebar_accordion();
  attribute_update_panel_set_active_button();
  annotation_editor_set_active_button();
  init_message_panel();
}
```

view.ts

```
inside this ts , I want to use _via_init() function which is from via.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the function from your js file.

```
export function _via_init() {
       ...
}
```

Now in your view.ts you simply import it like:

```
import * as via from 'path/to/assets/via.js'
```

And use it like:

```
via._via_init();
```

Comment: ImageAnnotatorComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: _assets_js_via_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__._via_init is not a function  ----------> Getting this error

Comment: could you update your question with the code you used to import the file and invoking the function?